# How to get known if QThread exited properly or was terminated?

Tags: qt, qthread, qt-signals

I have found in Qt 4.8 there was terminated signal as you can see here:
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qthread.html#terminated

But now in Qt 5.8 there is no such a thing. http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qthread.html

It seems finished signal is emmited if thread finished and even if thread is terminated. But is there option how to get known if QThread exited properly or was terminated?

Comment: terminated() was removed from Qt 5 because the emission of signal in the case of termination is not guaranteed

Comment: And from Qt5, doc says finished is emitted always even if terminated: If the associated thread was terminated using terminate(), it is undefined from which thread this signal is emitted, but it is emitted.

Comment: How would you use that information? If you knew exactly the thread is finished or terminated what would you do in your code?

Comment: Concerning the signal `finished()`: Can't the thread simply set a flag somewhere (e.g. in a member variable) when it finishes regulary. Hence, when the signal is received the receiver can check and find out whether thread has finished or was terminated. (Beside of this, I read in the doc. that _**Warning:** This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged._ but I assume you're aware about this.)

Comment: @Scheff Wow, so simple, I do not know why did not I think about set simple flag on end of run. I will try it! About danger of terminate i know. But I works with testing of hardware and user has to have option to hard stop procedure even in the middle of communication or something.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `QThread` - usually prefer `std::thread`. Whenever I looked for aborting a thread, I ended up with the hint to not to use the terminate/abort or whatever might be available as this can leave unreleased resources. Hence, in any case, a flag (preferably atomic) in the main loop of thread was the solution to force termination from "outside". In the case of `QThread`, the terminate may set such flag which is considered in the event loop of thread. I'm not sure how the terminate works if you don't use the event loop of `QThread`. The flag should always work. ;-)

Comment: The flag I mentioned in my last comment is a bit different from what I recommended earlier. It's rather something like `std::atomic<bool> stop;` and a thread main loop `for (stop = false; !stop;) { /* do thread things which should not consume too much time or check stop again for early out */ }`. The `atomic` grants that the `stop` flag can be set in any other thread and will be considered as soon as it's checked next time in the thread.

Comment: @Scheff Yep i understand what you mentioned but I would have to put flag hundreds of times between every call in thread job. For example if overcurrent occure then you want to kill procedure and turn all power supplies off immediately and not to wait for flag on next iteration.

Comment: That's an argument, and terminate might be the proper solution. I would have a look on the implementation (woboq.org has a nice website for this: [qthread.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp.html).) I don't know how safe your re-action of detected overcurrency has to be. For me, it sounds like detected overcurrency should set a flag (atomic, of course) and every related operation has to check this flag beforehand. The overcurrency itself is detected by...? (Interrupt?) This is, of course, my opinion only - without knowing details. ;-)

Comment: That's a joke: In [`qthead.cpp:790`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp.html#790) I found the following implemenation of `QThread::terminate()`: `void QThread::terminate()
{
}`. There must surely be OS dependent implementations... :-)

Comment: This looks much better: [`qthread_win.cpp:566`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp.html#566) - the Windows specific implementation. (There is another for *ix.)

Comment: @Scheff Overcurrency or others fatal faults are detected manually by user and he has to stop software. But back to main question, I used your proposal with additional flag and it of cource works fine. I think you can post it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following pattern proposed by @Scheff

```
class MyQThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__terminated = None
        super().__init__()

    def wasTerminated(self):
        if self.__terminated is None:
            return True
        return False

    def run(self):
        # Add at end of run
        self.__terminated = False
```

And following in caller:

```
class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.thread = MyQThread()
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.finishedSlot)

    def finishedSlot(self):
        if self.thread.wasTerminated():
            print("Thread was killed before finished")
        else:
            print("Thread results are ok")
```